# return array response to destination file jquery ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

am trying to populate fields automatically behalf of what user typed in particular input field. eg: i want to populate automatically `username` and `age` when someone type `fullname`, but trouble is when i receive data in array() i can only use it with single element either in age field or in username field, what i basically want is this ::

```
$.ajax({url: "/php/autofill.php?query="+query, success: function(result){
 $("#ajax").html(result);
}});
```

Can i just fetch that like below?

```
$.ajax({url: "/php/autofill.php?query="+query, success: function(result){
 $("#ajax").html(result.username);

//or

$("#ajax").html(result.age);
}});
```

**i know code is too dirty, but i want to do it like this way anyhow, looking for answers**

Comment: You can't unless your response data is json formatted.

Comment: That depends on how your server is sending response.

Comment: @guyfawkes how can i use it with json data type?

Comment: Can you add what do you get from your autofill.php response. Without seeing it you can try `var jsonResult = JSON.parse(result); $("#ajax").html(jsonResult.username);` but again your response might not be a json data at all.

Comment: its json object

Comment: array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(8) "mitch_yz"
    ["age"]=>
    int(2) 22

    }
  }